# Rails polymorphic join table work both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am starting to learn more advanced associations, and polymorphic join table looks very interesting, but I've come to a bad limitation.

**My models:**

**school_class.rb:**

```
class SchoolClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :class_of_schools, as: :school_model, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :basic_primary_schools, through: :class_of_schools
  has_many :basic_shugenja_schools, through: :class_of_schools
  has_many :basic_monk_schools, through: :class_of_schools
end
```

**class_of_school.rb:**

```
class ClassOfSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school_model, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :school_class
end
```

**basic_primary_School.rb:**

```
class BasicPrimarySchool < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :class_of_schools, as: :school_model, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :school_classes, through: :class_of_schools
end
```

shugenja_school and monk_schools, has the same association as basic_primary_school.

**And join model it self:**

```
class CreateClassOfSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :class_of_schools do |t|
      t.integer :school_class_id
      t.integer :school_model_id
      t.string :school_model_type

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

It joins well on the school side, I can make school.class_schools, and I get the array of school_classes associated. But on the other side I can`t do the same. In fact when I check school_class.classes_of schools I get empty array. 
I make associations in my seed file by function like this:

```
def join_schools_with_classes(school_object_name, school_classes_array)
  school_object_name.all.each do |school|
    school_classes = school_classes_array[school.name]
    school_classes.each do |class_name|
      school_class = SchoolClass.find_by(name: class_name)
      school.class_of_schools.create( school_class_id: school_class.id)
    end
  end
end
```

**My question:**

How can I make this association works both ways? So I can call `ClassSchool.first.class_of_schools` returns, all objects associated to this object. And still be able to call `BasicPrimarySchool.first.school_classes` to get associated `school_class` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `as: :school_model` in SchoolClass relation

```
has_many :class_of_schools, dependent: :destroy
```

**EDIT**

change the relation in `SchoolClass` to

`has_many :basic_primary_schools, through: :class_of_schools, source: :school_model, source_type: "BasicPrimarySchool"`

Comment: It worked as for the school_class.classes_of_school it now return array of those objects :)

but when I try to get SchoolClass.first.basic_primary_schools, I get `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s)`

Comment: The correct answer was `has_many :basic_primary_schools, through: :class_of_schools, source: :school_model, source_type: "BasicPrimarySchool"` But I will mark answer as correct please update it.